# Adapter Item Click From Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have ListView in My Fragment. I have some action button in my List Item. My Adapter is like below

```
public class StatAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity mActivity;
    private ArrayList<Stat> mData;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Drawable drawableOffline,drawableOnline;

    public StatAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Stat> data) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mData = new ArrayList<>();
        mData.addAll(data);

        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mActivity.getSystemService(AppCompatActivity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

         drawableOnline = activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.round_online);
         drawableOffline = activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.round_offline);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int pPosition, View pView, ViewGroup pParent) {
        pView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_stat, null,false);

        String name = mData.get(pPosition).getName();
        String first = name.substring(0, 1);

        TextView txtCount = pView.findViewById(R.id.txt_count);

        txtCount.setText(first);

        TextView txtName = pView.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
        txtName.setText(name);
        TextView txtNumber = pView.findViewById(R.id.txt_number);
        txtNumber.setText("Number: "+mData.get(pPosition).getNumber());

        int onlineBg = ResourcesCompat.getColor(mActivity.getResources(), R.color.onlineBg, null);
        int offlineBg = ResourcesCompat.getColor(mActivity.getResources(), R.color.offlineBg, null);
        int white = ResourcesCompat.getColor(mActivity.getResources(), R.color.colorWhite, null);
        int black = ResourcesCompat.getColor(mActivity.getResources(), R.color.colorBlack, null);


        ImageView btnGetCSV = pView.findViewById(R.id.btnGetCSV);
        ImageView btnNotificationOff = pView.findViewById(R.id.btnNotificationOff);
        ImageView btnNotificationOn = pView.findViewById(R.id.btnNotificationOn);
        ImageView btnNumberDetails = pView.findViewById(R.id.btnNumberDetails);
        ImageView btnRemoveNumber = pView.findViewById(R.id.btnRemoveNumber);

        btnGetCSV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Get CSV", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        btnNotificationOff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Notification Off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        btnNotificationOn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Notification On", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        btnNumberDetails.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Number Details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        btnRemoveNumber.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Remove Number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        TextView txtSatus = pView.findViewById(R.id.txt_status);
        txtSatus.setText(mData.get(pPosition).isOnline() ? "Online" : "Offline");

        if(mData.get(pPosition).isOnline()){
            txtCount.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drawableOnline,null,null,null);
        }else{
            txtCount.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drawableOffline,null,null,null);
        }


        txtCount.setTextColor(mData.get(pPosition).isOnline() ? white : black);
        txtCount.setBackgroundColor(mData.get(pPosition).isOnline() ? onlineBg : offlineBg);

        TextView txtTime = pView.findViewById(R.id.txt_time);
        txtTime.setText("Since " + mData.get(pPosition).getLastOnline());

        return pView;
    }

    public void setData(ArrayList<Stat> data) {
        mData.clear();
        mData.addAll(data);
        mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    public void addData(Stat data) {
        mData.add(data);
        mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    public void clearData() {
        mData.clear();
        mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    public Stat getStat(int position) {
        return mData.get(position);
    }
}
```

And My Fragment is like below

```
public class StateFragment extends Fragment {
    private final int PERMISSION_CONTACT = 10003;
    private final int PICK_CONTACT = 10;
    @BindView(R.id.list_stats)
    ListView mStatList;
    @BindView(R.id.swipe_refresh)
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefresh;
    EditText edtName, edtNumber;
    private Activity mActivity;
    private StatAdapter mAdapter;
    private Dialog mWaitDialog;
    ApiInterface apiService;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stats, container, false);
        mActivity = getActivity();
        apiService = ApiUtils.getAPIService(getContext());

        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        NumberData.getInstance();
        mAdapter = new StatAdapter(mActivity, NumberData.getInstance().mData);
        mStatList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mStatList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Stat stat = mAdapter.getStat(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, DetailLogActivity.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putSerializable(DetailLogActivity.DATA_OBJ, stat);
                bundle.putInt("position", position);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });

        swipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                refreshData();
            }
        });

        mWaitDialog = new Dialog(mActivity);
        mWaitDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        mWaitDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_wait);
        if (mWaitDialog.getWindow() != null) {
            mWaitDialog.getWindow().setLayout(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        }
        mWaitDialog.setCancelable(false);

        return view;
    }

    private void contact_permission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (mActivity.checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                AlertManager.createSingleCallbackAlert(mActivity, "We Need Your Permission",
                        "Please Grant Permission to Read Contacts to Access Number.", false, "OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @TargetApi(23)
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                dialogInterface.dismiss();
                                requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, PERMISSION_CONTACT);
                            }
                        });
            } else
                getContact();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_stats,menu);

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.actionCompare){
            compare();
            return  true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_CONTACT: {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    getContact();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(mActivity.getApplicationContext(), "You Can Not Load Number from Contact", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void getContact() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
    }

    private void refreshData() {
        NumberData.getInstance().mData.clear();
        mAdapter.clearData();
        apiService.getNumbers(NumberData.getInstance().mUserEmail).enqueue(new retrofit2.Callback<GetNumberCallback>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(retrofit2.Call<GetNumberCallback> call, retrofit2.Response<GetNumberCallback> response) {
                try {
                    GetNumberCallback numberCallback = response.body();

                    if (numberCallback.getCode() == 1) {

                        for (int i = 0; i < numberCallback.getNumber().size(); i++) {
                            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
                            sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));
                            Date mDate = sdf.parse(numberCallback.getLastOnline().get(i));
                            long lastOnlineTime = mDate.getTime();
                            NumberData.getInstance().mData.add(new Stat(numberCallback.getName().get(i), numberCallback.getNumber().get(i),

                                    numberCallback.getStatus().get(i)==1, formatDate(lastOnlineTime)));
                        }
                        mAdapter.setData(NumberData.getInstance().mData);
                    } else {
                        AlertManager.createSingleCallbackAlert(mActivity, "Error", "Server Problem",
                                false, "Retry", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                } catch (Exception pE) {

                }
                if (swipeRefresh.isRefreshing()) {
                    mActivity.runOnUiThread((new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
                        }
                    }));
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(retrofit2.Call<GetNumberCallback> call, Throwable t) {
                call.cancel();
                AlertManager.createSingleCallbackAlert(mActivity, "Unknown Error",
                        "Error reaching server", false, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                if (swipeRefresh.isRefreshing()) {
                    mActivity.runOnUiThread((new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
                        }
                    }));
                }
            }
        });
    }



    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        if (mAdapter != null) {
            //mAdapter.setData(NumberData.getInstance().mData);
            refreshData();
        }
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (reqCode) {
            case (PICK_CONTACT):
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri contactData = data.getData();
                    Cursor c = mActivity.managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                        String id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                        String hasPhone = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

                        if (hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                            Cursor phones = mActivity.getContentResolver().query(
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id,
                                    null, null);
                            assert phones != null;
                            phones.moveToFirst();
                            edtNumber.setText(phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex("data1")));
                            phones.close();
                        }
                        edtName.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)));


                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private String getDateTime() {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "dd MMM, HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
        Date date = new Date();
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }

    private String formatDate(long time) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "dd MMM, HH:mm:ss ", Locale.US);
        Date date = new Date(time);
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }
}
```

You can see that there some action button `btnGetCSV` etc in my adapter in which I am able to implement onclick but its hard to implement some function in adapter, so I am thinking to do it from Fragment. I am new in android and don't know how I can do it from fragment. Let me know if someone can give me example for do it. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need create interface "OnMenuItemClickListener" with callback methods in you adapter like this way.

```
public class StatAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity mActivity;
    private ArrayList<Stat> mData;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Drawable drawableOffline,drawableOnline;
    private OnMenuItemClickListener onMenuItemClickListener;

    public StatAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Stat> data,OnMenuItemClickListener onMenuItemClickListener) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mData = new ArrayList<>();
        mData.addAll(data);
        this.onMenuItemClickListener = onMenuItemClickListener;

        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mActivity.getSystemService(AppCompatActivity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

         drawableOnline = activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.round_online);
         drawableOffline = activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.round_offline);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int pPosition, View pView, ViewGroup pParent) {
        pView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_stat, null,false);

        String name = mData.get(pPosition).getName();
        String first = name.substring(0, 1);

        TextView txtCount = pView.findViewById(R.id.txt_count);

        txtCount.setText(first);

        TextView txtName = pView.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
        txtName.setText(name);
        TextView txtNumber = pView.findViewById(R.id.txt_number);
        txtNumber.setText("Number: "+mData.get(pPosition).getNumber());

        int onlineBg = ResourcesCompat.getColor(mActivity.getResources(), R.color.onlineBg, null);
        int offlineBg = ResourcesCompat.getColor(mActivity.getResources(), R.color.offlineBg, null);
        int white = ResourcesCompat.getColor(mActivity.getResources(), R.color.colorWhite, null);
        int black = ResourcesCompat.getColor(mActivity.getResources(), R.color.colorBlack, null);


        ImageView btnGetCSV = pView.findViewById(R.id.btnGetCSV);
        ImageView btnNotificationOff = pView.findViewById(R.id.btnNotificationOff);
        ImageView btnNotificationOn = pView.findViewById(R.id.btnNotificationOn);
        ImageView btnNumberDetails = pView.findViewById(R.id.btnNumberDetails);
        ImageView btnRemoveNumber = pView.findViewById(R.id.btnRemoveNumber);

        btnGetCSV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                onMenuItemClickListener.onGetCSVClick();
            }
        });
        btnNotificationOff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                onMenuItemClickListener.onNotificationOffClick();
            }
        });
        btnNotificationOn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                onMenuItemClickListener.onNotificationOnClick();
            }
        });
        btnNumberDetails.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                onMenuItemClickListener.onNumberDetailsClick();
            }
        });
        btnRemoveNumber.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                onMenuItemClickListener.onRemoveNumberClick();
            }
        });

        TextView txtSatus = pView.findViewById(R.id.txt_status);
        txtSatus.setText(mData.get(pPosition).isOnline() ? "Online" : "Offline");

        if(mData.get(pPosition).isOnline()){
            txtCount.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drawableOnline,null,null,null);
        }else{
            txtCount.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drawableOffline,null,null,null);
        }


        txtCount.setTextColor(mData.get(pPosition).isOnline() ? white : black);
        txtCount.setBackgroundColor(mData.get(pPosition).isOnline() ? onlineBg : offlineBg);

        TextView txtTime = pView.findViewById(R.id.txt_time);
        txtTime.setText("Since " + mData.get(pPosition).getLastOnline());

        return pView;
    }

    public void setData(ArrayList<Stat> data) {
        mData.clear();
        mData.addAll(data);
        mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    public void addData(Stat data) {
        mData.add(data);
        mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    public void clearData() {
        mData.clear();
        mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    public Stat getStat(int position) {
        return mData.get(position);
    }


    public interface OnMenuItemClickListener
    {
        void onGetCSVClick();
        void onNotificationOffClick();
        void onNotificationOnClick();
        void onNumberDetailsClick();
        void onRemoveNumberClick();
    }
}
```

Now you need to pass "this" in the constructor of adapter class like this way need to override all the call back method of interface into fragment then you get click event into fragment.

```
public class StateFragment extends Fragment implements StatAdapter.OnMenuItemClickListener {
    private final int PERMISSION_CONTACT = 10003;
    private final int PICK_CONTACT = 10;
    @BindView(R.id.list_stats)
    ListView mStatList;
    @BindView(R.id.swipe_refresh)
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefresh;
    EditText edtName, edtNumber;
    private Activity mActivity;
    private StatAdapter mAdapter;
    private Dialog mWaitDialog;
    ApiInterface apiService;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stats, container, false);
        mActivity = getActivity();
        apiService = ApiUtils.getAPIService(getContext());

        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        NumberData.getInstance();
        mAdapter = new StatAdapter(mActivity, new ArrayList<String>(),this);
        mStatList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mStatList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Stat stat = mAdapter.getStat(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, DetailLogActivity.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putSerializable(DetailLogActivity.DATA_OBJ, stat);
                bundle.putInt("position", position);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });

        swipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                refreshData();
            }
        });

        mWaitDialog = new Dialog(mActivity);
        mWaitDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        mWaitDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_wait);
        if (mWaitDialog.getWindow() != null) {
            mWaitDialog.getWindow().setLayout(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        }
        mWaitDialog.setCancelable(false);

        return view;
    }

    private void contact_permission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (mActivity.checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                AlertManager.createSingleCallbackAlert(mActivity, "We Need Your Permission",
                        "Please Grant Permission to Read Contacts to Access Number.", false, "OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @TargetApi(23)
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                dialogInterface.dismiss();
                                requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, PERMISSION_CONTACT);
                            }
                        });
            } else
                getContact();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_stats,menu);

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.actionCompare){
            compare();
            return  true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_CONTACT: {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    getContact();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(mActivity.getApplicationContext(), "You Can Not Load Number from Contact", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void getContact() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
    }

    private void refreshData() {
        NumberData.getInstance().mData.clear();
        mAdapter.clearData();
        apiService.getNumbers(NumberData.getInstance().mUserEmail).enqueue(new retrofit2.Callback<GetNumberCallback>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(retrofit2.Call<GetNumberCallback> call, retrofit2.Response<GetNumberCallback> response) {
                try {
                    GetNumberCallback numberCallback = response.body();

                    if (numberCallback.getCode() == 1) {

                        for (int i = 0; i < numberCallback.getNumber().size(); i++) {
                            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
                            sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));
                            Date mDate = sdf.parse(numberCallback.getLastOnline().get(i));
                            long lastOnlineTime = mDate.getTime();
                            NumberData.getInstance().mData.add(new Stat(numberCallback.getName().get(i), numberCallback.getNumber().get(i),

                                    numberCallback.getStatus().get(i)==1, formatDate(lastOnlineTime)));
                        }
                        mAdapter.setData(NumberData.getInstance().mData);
                    } else {
                        AlertManager.createSingleCallbackAlert(mActivity, "Error", "Server Problem",
                                false, "Retry", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                } catch (Exception pE) {

                }
                if (swipeRefresh.isRefreshing()) {
                    mActivity.runOnUiThread((new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
                        }
                    }));
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(retrofit2.Call<GetNumberCallback> call, Throwable t) {
                call.cancel();
                AlertManager.createSingleCallbackAlert(mActivity, "Unknown Error",
                        "Error reaching server", false, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                if (swipeRefresh.isRefreshing()) {
                    mActivity.runOnUiThread((new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
                        }
                    }));
                }
            }
        });
    }



    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        if (mAdapter != null) {
            //mAdapter.setData(NumberData.getInstance().mData);
            refreshData();
        }
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (reqCode) {
            case (PICK_CONTACT):
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri contactData = data.getData();
                    Cursor c = mActivity.managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                        String id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                        String hasPhone = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

                        if (hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                            Cursor phones = mActivity.getContentResolver().query(
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id,
                                    null, null);
                            assert phones != null;
                            phones.moveToFirst();
                            edtNumber.setText(phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex("data1")));
                            phones.close();
                        }
                        edtName.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)));


                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private String getDateTime() {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "dd MMM, HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
        Date date = new Date();
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }

    private String formatDate(long time) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "dd MMM, HH:mm:ss ", Locale.US);
        Date date = new Date(time);
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }

    @Override
    public void onGetCSVClick() {
        Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Get CSV", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationOffClick() {
        Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Notification Off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationOnClick() {
        Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Notification On", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNumberDetailsClick() {
        Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Number Details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRemoveNumberClick() {
        Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Remove Number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```